# Did anybody run the sample code of Liferay Portal Systems Development(2012) successfully on liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm learning Liferay Portal Systems Development 2012 by Jonas X. Yuan. I tried to run sample code knowledge-base-portlet of chapter 3, but so many errors show up, like social-equity doesn't exist, viewJSP is not defined in java file etc., did anybody run it successfully on liferay 6.1.1? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if he's using Liferay's standard knowledgebase plugin that you can find on the [marketplace](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15197613) (source is available there or on [github](https://github.com/olafk/liferay-plugins/tree/6.1.x/portlets/knowledge-base-portlet)). It seems that the book is for 6.0 (couldn't find the information on the website, but it's released in January 2012), and it seems that knowledgebase is accessing deprecated APIs. Social Equity in Liferay 6.0 is called Social Activity in Liferay 6.1.

Comment: the one on github should be the same as the sample code, after lots of efforts, I could run it. thanks for your information

Comment: it might be the same plugin, but it's been developed further between 6.0 and 6.1 - the 6.0 branch is not on github, maybe it's tagged or you might find it somewhere in the history of that project. However, if the 6.1 version runs, don't bother to search for it and just be happy that you have found the running code. Of course it doesn't match the book then, but that's life when the book is for a different version than the one you're using.